# How to trace value assigned to local variable(variables in Module)?

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, core-language, scoping, debugging

**Bug introduced in v10.1 or earlier and persists through v11.3**

CASE:4240757

---

Here is my code:

```
Trace[Module[{x}, x = 1; x = 2; x = 3; j = 6; j = 7], x = _, MatchLocalNames -> True]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

I want to trace the value set to local variable `x`, however, it seems that the pattern `x = _` could not match.

And if I change the pattern to `_ = _`, it does.

```
Trace[Module[{x}, x = 1; x = 2; x = 3; j = 6; j = 7], _ = _, MatchLocalNames -> True]
```

> ```
> {{{x$32240=1},{x$32240=2},{x$32240=3},{j=6},{j=7}}}
> ```

And if I trace the variable `j`:

```
Trace[Module[{x}, x = 1; x = 2; x = 3; j = 6; j = 7], j = _, MatchLocalNames -> True]
```

> ```
>  {{{j=6},{j=7}}}
> ```

So, it seems that the pattern `x = _` could not match the local variables `x` inside the `Module`? I have look at the documentation and set the `MatchLocalNames` to `True`, but it doesn't make use (though it is set to `True` by default). The version is 11.3.

I get this problem when read through the book *Power Programming With Mathematica* page 415. The code is:

```
iterSqrt[x_] := Module[{i, j, xn = 1}, While[Abs[xn^2 - x] > 10^-6, i = x/xn;j = xn + i;xn = j/2];xn]
```

And when trace the variable assigned to `xn`: `Trace[iterSqrt[2], xn = _]` , I
get `{}`. And it is not as same as that answers on book:

> ```
> {{xn$14 = 1}, {{{xn$14 = 3/2}}, {{xn$14 = 17/2}}, {{xn$14 = 577/408}}, {{xn$14 = 665857/470832}}}}
> ```

Comment: Problem persists in MMA12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I missed something more straightforward, anyway:

```
Trace[
  Module[{x}, x = 1; x = 2; x = 3; j = 6; j = 7], 
  HoldPattern[s_Symbol = _] /; StringStartsQ["x"] @ SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ s
]
```

> {{{x$13372=1},{x$13372=2},{x$13372=3}}}

I reported `Trace[Module[{x}, x = 1], x = _]` as a generic example and it was confirmed as a bug:

> It does appear that Trace[] is not behaving as described in the documentation. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided.